# Convert Date to String Laravel

Tags: laravel

For a vuetify component I need the date but in a String or else I get this error

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "now". Expected String with value "Thu Jan 02 2020 13:05:39 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)", got Date

How can I convert this to a String, the format is correct I just need it to be a String

```
$today = new Date();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Carbon\Carbon` for that. Something like `Carbon::parse($today)->format(d-m-Y)` for example

Comment: if I try this then I get `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: what you put in parse method as parameter?

Comment: $today = new Date();
$now = Carbon::parse($today)->format("d-m-Y");

Comment: oh, that's easy one: `Carbon::now()->format(d-m-Y)` or whatever format you like

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php [date](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) function, e.g:

```
$dateAsString = date('Y-m-d') // 2020-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = new DateTime();
die($today->format(DateTime::RFC7231));
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: link only comment